# Power Bi forecast projected sales accross days / months between a date range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a monthly forecast for a list of clients that have different start and end dates for their spending.

I am able to create a formula that would work in excel, but am learning Power Bi and having troubles converting the formula to something that would work inside Power Bi without adding the formula to excel file. Column A-F are how the raw data is delivered. Columns G-R are columns that i am trying to avoid adding thru a Dax formula

[Pending Sample excel data](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AnuwyqF23e77kC6hAS-qeThLyRts?e=EEklWi)

Answer (score 0):

it might help if you unpivot the prorate monthly amounts in  power query first (since narrow tables better than wide tables)
client    Start Date    End Date    PendingMarket$  PendingShare Month Value
Client 1    3/1/2021    3/1/2021    $10,618           3.0%         jan   0
Client 1    3/1/2021    3/1/2021    $10,618           3.0%         feb   0
Client 1    3/1/2021    3/1/2021    $10,618           3.0%         mar   319

then the dax formulae is easy

for a calculated column on the table:
Pending Station $ (Prorated) = CALCULATE(SUM(MyTableName[Value]), [Strat Date] = Earlier([Start Date], [End Date] = Earlier[End Date], [Client] = Earlier[Client])

PN earlier get the value of current row for column value

Comment: Thank you, That was so helpful and I am now kicking myself for missing that easy solution.

Comment: You are welcome.  Please mark as the answer.